# Remove last comma java

Tags: java, sql, arrays

I am trying to insert an element into table from a 2D array.
I have a problem in removing the last comma to write the sql statement in a proper way

This is the code

```
            String m="";
            String matInsert = null;
            for (int k=0;k<di.mat.length;k++) {  //row
            for (int j=0;j<di.mat[k].length;j++) {

                m+=di.mat[k][j]+", ";
                matInsert=new String("INSERT INTO "+ tableName  +"("+ff+")"+"values" +"("+m+")");   

        }
            m = m.replaceAll(", $","");
            //m=m.substring(0,m.lastIndexOf(","));
            System.out.println(matInsert);
            stmt1.executeUpdate(matInsert);
            }
```

I tried very much but i did not succeed to remove it

please help.

Comment: Why are you doing parameter substitution by hand? This is a recipe for an injection attack.

Comment: Use Prepared statement is what David is suggesting or someone can change the parameters (by special on screen values for text boxes) and do bad things to your data base. details at OWASP website https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commonly use the following structure for this type of thing

```
String sep = "";
for(...) {
    m += (sep+di.mat[k][j]);
    sep = ",";
}
```

It isn't the nicest but it works.

Now, part of the problem in your code is that you are creating matInsert inside the loop then updating m after the loop and not rebuilding it.

Updated code:

```
 String matInsert = null;
 for (int k=0;k<di.mat.length;k++) {  //row
    String m="";
    String sep = "";
    for (int j=0;j<di.mat[k].length;j++) {
        m+= (sep+di.mat[k][j]);
        sep = " ,";
    }
    matInsert="INSERT INTO "+ tableName  +"("+ff+")"+"values" +"("+m+")";   
    System.out.println(matInsert);
    stmt1.executeUpdate(matInsert);
 }
```

Comment: Of course, looking at this the next day, I realize we should have been recommending StringBuilder :)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid last comma addition with simple logic. It is good idea to omit unnecessary thing on spot, rather than to replace that with another operation.

```
for (int k=0;k<di.mat.length;k++) {  //row
  for (int j=0;j<di.mat[k].length;j++) {
    m+=di.mat[k][j];

    if(j<di.mat[k].length -1){ //This condition will escape you from last comma addition
      m+= ", ";    
    }
  }
}
```

Another point, use `StringBuilder#append` instead of `String` `+` concat to increase the efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Since m is a String, you can use m.substring(0,m.length()-1) or add and if statement inside the inner loop checking if it is the last index of k and j then don't add a comma at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the last instance of a character in a string, as in delete it, use this:

```
public class Something
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "test";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        char delval = 'c';

        int lastIndex = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length()-1; i++)
        {
            if(s.charAt(i) == delval)
            {
                lastIndex = i;
            }
        }

        try{
            sb.deleteCharAt(lastIndex);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Value not present");
        }
    }

}
```